# In Odoo 11, at a Kanban view, readonly attr didn't work

Tags: odoo, readonly, odoo-11, kanban

In odoo 11, for a kanban view. I want to set the records can not be drag and drop. The records are columed by a filed name 'ms', and I set the ms `attr` to `readonly='1'`, and it works.

```
<field name="milestone" readonly="1"/>
```

But when i try to use another way to set readonly depend on anther var, if_set_ms_readonly by this way, it didn't work.

```
<field name="set_ms_readonly"/>
<field name="milestone" attrs="{'readonly':[('set_ms_readonly','=','True')]}"/>
```

I have make sure that `set_ms_readonly` is True. But however, it seems `readonly` is not set to True. But I don't know where is wrong.

```
<field name="milestone" readonly="1"/>   works!
```

didn't work:

```
<field name="set_ms_readonly"/>
<field name="milestone" attrs="{'readonly':[('set_ms_readonly','=','True')]}"/>
```

But the two way should be equal in logic.

Comment: "<field name="set_ms_readonly"/>     <field name="milestone" attrs="{'readonly':[('set_ms_readonly','=',True)]}"/>  "    This didn't work.   But "<field name="milestone" readonly="1"/>   "  this line works. I think the two ways should be equal in logic. I have make sure that set_ms_readonly is True. How can I set readonly to True by the attr= way ? Or can you tell me what is the difference of the two ways.

Comment: The porblem when I tried you first method I didn't work, I can still drug and drop the items?

Comment: Can I see your code ? It should be columed by the field in kanban...                                                                                                                                 
 By the way, It is a typo in the main description. The domain express is " ('set_ms_readonly','=', True)  " which should be no problem.

Comment: No I used this technique on another model, I converted the code to make a field readonly then I grouped the record by this field, then dragged a record and everything worked nicely If you want to prevent this behavior by raising an error I think I have a way to do this. but he still can dragged but when the record it's released an error will be raised

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your field ""set_ms_readonly" is Boolean.

Because "set_ms_readonly" is char or another then it will check value like ("char_value", "=", "True"). So, True is not found so field is not be read only.

Comment: Yes. set_ms_readonly is defined with Boolean type.                                                              def _set_ms_read_only(self):
 for record in self:
  record.set_ms_readonly = self.env.user.has_group('dh_matter.group_dh_fee_earner')

set_ms_readonly = fields.Boolean(string='Set Milestone Readonly', compute='_set_ms_read_only')